# Using HTML entity codes with Javascript methods like inludes() and charAt()

Tags: javascript, html, methods, entity

I am trying to build a tool to help me memorize the guitar fretboard and I want to include a feature that lets me switch between sharp notes and flat notes. I'm almost there but some of Javascript's methods don't seem to recognise HTML entity codes. The first function works fine when I assign the ball.innerHTML to flat notes. The problem occurs when I try to switch back to sharps using the sharpFunc().

```
function nextChar(char) {
    return String.fromCharCode(char.charCodeAt(0) + 1);
}

flatNote.addEventListener('click', flatFunc);
function flatFunc() {
    ballArray.forEach(function(ball) {
        ball.innerHTML.includes('#') ? 
        ball.innerHTML = nextChar(ball.innerHTML).concat('&#9837;') : ball.innerHTML;
        ball.innerHTML.includes('H') ? ball.innerHTML = `A&#9837;` : ball;
    })
}

// function prevChar(char) {
//     return String.fromCharCode(char.charCodeAt(0) - 1);
// }

sharpNote.addEventListener('click', sharpFunc);
function sharpFunc() {
    ballArray.forEach(function(ball) {
        ball.innerHTML.includes('U+0266D;') ? 
        ball.innerHTML = 'oh' : ball.innerHTML;
    })
}
```

I have tried using different types of code to represent the flat note and I have tried numerous types of conditionals. Nothing is working.

Comment: Provide your html code and the error you got

Comment: I have figured out the problem now. To my knowledge, javascript methods render strings literally which is why the entity code wasn't recognised by the .includes() method. To get around this issue, I stored the entity as a variable.